If $\text P[s+t<τ]=\text P[s<τ]\text P[t<τ]$ and $\mathcal F_t:=σ(\bigcup_{s\le t}\{τ\le s\})$, can we factorize $\text P[s+t<τ\mid\mathcal F_s]$?
Let $\tau$ be a $[0,\infty)$ valued random variable on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $$\operatorname P[s+t<\tau]=\operatorname P[s<\tau]\operatorname P[t<\tau]\tag1\;\;\;\text{for all }s,t\ge0$$ and $$\mathcal F_t:=\sigma\left(\left\{\tau\le s\right\}:s\in[0,\;t]\right)\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0.$$
Given $s,t\ge0$, can we simplify $\operatorname P[s+t<\tau\mid\mathcal F_s]$? Does it factor as well? I'm not sure how to approach this. Is there a nicer generator for $\mathcal F_s$ on which we can prove an identity?

An example of a $\tau$ satisfying $(1)$ is an exponentially distributed one.

If $\lim_{h\searrow 0} \frac{P[h<\tau]-1}{h} = -\lambda$ for some $\lambda \in (0,\infty)$ then $\tau \sim Exp(\lambda)$.

@Michael Yes, but what do you want to point out? $(1)$ is not sufficient to conclude that $\tau$ has exponential distribution. Could also be Weibull distribution, for example.

The only time a Wiebull distribution satisfies (1) is when its parameters are chosen to make it an exponential distribution.

Perhaps I am misunderstanding. Do you have $\bigcup\limits_{s\in[0,;t]}\left{\tau\le s\right} = {\tau \le t}$?  Is it possible to have $\tau \le s$ and $s+t < \tau$?

@Henry : Good point. I was unwittingly treating that as the sigma algebra generated by those events, but to write that we would need union of $\sigma({\tau\leq v})$.

@Henry Yes, sorry. Fixed the definition.

@Michael You are right. I made a mistake in my thoughts on that.

To repeat my second question earlier, is it possible to have $τ≤s$ and $s+t<τ$?

@Henry Of course not, since $t\ge0$ this would imply $s<s$.

But you seem to be asking for the probability $s+t<\tau$ conditioned on $\tau \le s$

@Henry Yes, that's correct and not a contradiction to what I wrote earlier. That's the memoryless property of the exponential distribution.

Generally, for any nonnegative random variable $\tau:\Omega\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ and any $s\geq 0$ we have
$$\mathcal{F}_s=\sigma(\cup_{v \in [0,s]}\sigma(\{\tau \leq v\})) = \sigma(Y)$$
where we define the random variable
$$Y=\tau 1_{\{\tau\leq s\}} + (s+1)1_{\{\tau>s\}}$$
This can be seen by observing:
$$\{Y=s+1\} \iff \{\tau>s\}$$
and for all $y\in [0,s]$:
$$\{Y\leq y\} \iff \{\tau\leq y\} $$

Then for your problem, given any $s\geq 0$, $t\geq 0$:
\begin{align}
P[s+t<\tau|\mathcal{F}_s]&=P[s+t<\tau | Y]\\
&=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \mbox{if $Y\leq s$} \\
P[s+t<\tau | \tau>s] & \mbox{if $Y=s+1$} 
\end{array}\right.\\
&=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \mbox{if $Y\leq s$} \\
P[t<\tau] & \mbox{if $Y=s+1$} 
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

Note I have fixed this to taking a union of $\sigma(\{\tau\leq v\})$ (so a union of sigma algebras, rather than events) as per Henry’s comment. In other words, $\mathcal{F}_s$ is the sigma algebra generated by the collection of events of the type $\{\tau\leq v\}$ for $v\in[0,s]$.

Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, that's a quite unhandy expression, since it involves the obscure variable $Y$. Please see my answer for a nicer expression. It should be correct, but please feel free to correct me if I made a mistake.

Recall that ${Y\leq s}={\tau\leq s}$ and ${Y=s+1}={\tau>s}$.

Yeah, sorry. So, it's actually the same as my formula, right?

Yes it is the same as $P[\tau>t]1_{{\tau>s}}$. You had asked is there a nice generator for $\mathcal{F}_s$ and $Y$ seems to be the nicest. Note that I am treating $\mathcal{F}_s$ as the sigma algebra generated by the collection of events ${\tau\leq v}$ for $v \in [0,s]$, rather than just the sigma algebra generated by ${\tau \leq s]$.

Unfortunately, Michael's answer is not really the expression what I was looking for. However, we should have $$\left.\operatorname P[s+t<\tau\mid\mathcal F_s]\right|_{\{\;s\;<\;\tau\;\}}=\left.\operatorname P\right|_{\{\;s\;<\;\tau\;\}}\left[s+t<\tau,s<\tau\mid\left.\mathcal F_s\right|_{\{\;s\;<\;\tau\;\}}\right]\tag1$$ $\left.\operatorname P\right|_{\{\;s\;<\;\tau\;\}}$-almost surely. Now, $$\left.\{\{\tau\le r\}:r\in[0,s]\}\right|_{\{\;\tau\;>\;s\;\}}=\{\emptyset\}\tag2$$ and hence $$\left.\mathcal F_s\right|_{\{\;s\;<\;\tau\;\}}=\{\emptyset,\{\tau>s\}\}\tag3.$$ That is, the right-hand side of $(1)$ is $$\left.\operatorname P\right|_{\{\;s\;<\;\tau\;\}}=\frac{\operatorname P[s+t<\tau,s<\tau]}{\operatorname P[s<\tau]}=\operatorname P[t<\tau]\tag4.$$ From that we conclude $$\operatorname P[s+t<\tau\mid\mathcal F_s]=1_{\{\;s\;<\;\tau\;\}}\operatorname P[s+t<\tau\mid\mathcal F_s]=1_{\{\;s\;<\;\tau\;\}}\operatorname P[t<\tau]\tag5.$$

Now I need some help to get some abstract nonsense right. I think we have actually shown that $$M_t:=1_{[0,\;\tau)}=1_{\{\;t\;<\;\tau\;\}}\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ is a time-homogeneous Markov process. In fact, the filtration generated by $M$ should precisely be $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$. Now $(5)$ reads $$\operatorname P[M_{s+t}=1\mid\mathcal F_s]=M_s\operatorname P[t<\tau]\tag6$$ for all $s,t\ge0$. What is the transition semigroup $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ of $M$? Each $\kappa_t$ must be a Markov kernel on $\{0,1\}$ equipped with the power set $\sigma$-algebra. And $(6)$ must be equal to $\kappa_t(M_s,\{1\})$.
